# How to convert signed byte array to ascii in Java

Tags: java, arrays, ascii, signed

In Java program
I have signed byte array as

`[-112, 21, 64, 0, 7, 50, 54, 127]`

how i can convert into ascii number
which is equal to

```
901540000732367F
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ascii number"? Do you actually mean hexadecimal number?

Comment: yes hexadecimal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the order of bytes in the result is reverse to that of the array, so you should iterate the array in the reverse order and add each element with a shift by the predefined number of bits:

```java
private static String convertToHexFullByte(byte[] arr) {
    return convertToHex(arr, 8);
}
    
private static String convertToHexHalfByte(byte[] arr) {
    return convertToHex(arr, 4);
}
    
private static String convertToHex(byte[] arr, int bits) {
    long mask = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
        mask |= 1 << i;
    }
    long res = 0;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j += bits) {
        res |= (arr[i] & mask) << j;
    }

    return Long.toHexString(res).toUpperCase();        
}
```

Test

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte[] arr4 = {49, 55, 48, 51, 55};
        
    System.out.println(convertToHexHalfByte(arr4));
        
    byte[] arr8 = {-112, 21, 64, 0, 7, 50, 54, 127};
        
    System.out.println(convertToHexFullByte(arr8));
}
```

output

```
17037
901540000732367F
```

Comment: Its givinf me this ffffffff9747767f

Comment: @NRaj yes, fixed that

Comment: Its working, btw why its not working for another {49, 55, 48, 51, 55}; which should be 17037

Comment: How come?  You have 5 positive bytes as input and the result is supposed to be 3 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works by:

- streaming the indices of the byte array
- maping to an int and getting rid of the sign extension
- reducing to a long by shift and or operations.

```
byte[] bytes = { -112, 21, 64, 0, 7, 50, 54, 127 };

long lng = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
        .mapToLong(i -> bytes[i] & 0xff)
        .reduce(0L, (a, b) -> (a << 8) | b);

System.out.println("long decimal value = " + lng);
System.out.println("long hex value = " + Long.toHexString(lng));
```

prints

```
long decimal value = -8064469188872096129
long hex value = 901540000732367f
```

Using the same technique, the other example of `{49, 55, 48, 51, 55}`
should be:

```
long decimal value = 211379303223
long hex value = 3137303337
```

Comment: Yes its working, but when i will have unsigned array {49, 55, 48, 51, 55}; => 17037 how to handle. can i use same solution for signed and unsigned byte array.

Comment: Yes, it will work.  But `17037` is not a hex conversion it is the last digit of `[31,37,30,33,37]` which is the hex value of each byte.